# How to compile a C program with Visual Studio on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I am trying to compile a library for 2D localization called **libdots** [which can be found on this website](http://chili.epfl.ch/libdots) with Visual Studio 2015 on Windows for x86 or x64.

The following is stated in the readme file of the lib:

> It is written in pure c and has no external library dependencies other
>   than 'libc'.

What I have done so far:

- Installed [OpenCV 3.0.0](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) to C:/opencv
- Installed [CMake for Windows](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/)
- Installed [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Set the following `System Environment Variable`:

```
OPENCV_DIR    C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12
```

Added the following to the `Path` variable in Windows settings:

```
%OPENCV_DIR%;
C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib;
C:\opencv\build\include;
C:\opencv\build\include\opencv;
C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2
```

Then I configured and generated the Makefile with cmake-gui and selected `Visual Studio 14 2015` generator with "Use default native compilers":

[image]

This produced a Visual Studio Solution file (*.sln). Opening this file shows me the complete C project in the IDE. But when trying to build the project, I get the following errors:

[image]

Does somebody have a hint how to proceed and/or solve these issues?

Comment: Looks like C99's Variable length array support was never supported by Visual Studio; not even in VS 2010 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zb1574zs(v=vs.100).aspx  So you have to edit the code, or use a different compiler

Comment: Sample: Line 145 `int maxima[numMax];` numMax is not a constant, making this not standard compliant C++. Visual Studio adheres to this part of the standard, so you are SOL, dude. Much re-writing of code will be required to make this work under Visual Studio (and a lot of other C++ compilers)

Comment: Have you tried using CMake and selecting mingw as the compiler, since you went through the trouble of installing it?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. I am basically not bound to Visual Studio. So let me try with the mingw compiler... I will be back right after the attempt.

Comment: You might consider using Visual Studio's C++ compiler, it's (mostly) backward compatible with C.  All you have to do is rename the files from .c to .cpp